# Apply the Array.map() method to the comment data stored in the parent's state and pass to child

Tags: reactjs

I am just a beginner at learning React! (3 weeks). I cloned the Instagram main page for practicing and I tried to make a comment component and apply the Array.map() method to the comment data stored in the parent's state so that as many comment components as the number of comments appear. When I do this without comment component it works well

```
<ul className="feed-comments">
                {/* <Comment commentAddList={this.states.commentList} /> */}
                <li>hello</li>
                {this.state.commentList.map((comm, idx) => {
                  return <li key={idx}>{comm}</li>;
                })}
                
              </ul>
```

However, when I create Comment Component and passing parent's state to child's component in Comment.js it doesn' work
and the error message : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'commentList')

```
<ul className="feed-comments">
                <Comment commentAddList={this.states.commentList} />
              </ul>
```

This is Comment.js in Component folder

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Comment extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {/* <li>hello</li> */}
        {this.props.commentAddList.map((comm, idx) => {
          return <li key={idx}>{comm}</li>;
        })}
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Comment;
```

I will leave the whole code below just in case!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import "../../styles/common.scss";
import './Feed.scss';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {
  faHeart,
  faComment,
  faPaperPlane,
  faBookmark,
  faEllipsisH,
} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import Comment from '../../../compoonents/Comment/Comment';

class Feed extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      commentList: [],
    };
  }

  getValue = event => {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  addComment = () => {
    this.setState({
      commentList: this.state.commentList.concat([this.state.value]),
      value: '',
    });
  };

  addCommEnter = e => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      this.addComment();
    }
  };
  // enterClick = e => {
  //   if (e.key === 'Enter') {
  //     this.buttonClick;
  //     e.target.value = '';
  //   }
  // };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="feeds">
        <div className="article">
          <div className="identi">
            <img className="selfi-identi" alt="selfi-img" src="about.png" />
            <span className="name"> Jiwan Jeon </span>

            {/* <i id="test" class="fa fa-ellipsis-h" aria-hidden="true"></i> */}
            <div className="faEllipsisH">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsisH} />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="pic">
            <img id="feed-pic" src="ucscPic.png" />
          </div>

          <div className="show-box">
            <div className="reaction-icons">
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} className="heart" />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faComment} className="comment" />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPaperPlane} className="plane" />
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBookmark} className="bookMark" />
            </div>

            <div className="like-counts">
              <span>like 4,000</span>
            </div>

            <div className="check-comments">
              <span>
                UC Santa Cruz will continue to offer most courses remotely or
                online for spring and summer 2021, providing in-person
                instruction for a small
              </span>
              <a id="space" href="">
                expanding
              </a>
              <br />
              <a href="">Check the all comments</a>
              <ul className="feed-comments">
                <Comment commentAddList={this.states.commentList} />
                {/* <li>hello</li> */}
                {/* {this.state.commentList.map((comm, idx) => {
                  return <li key={idx}>{comm}</li>;
                })} */}
                
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="comment">
            <i className="fa fa-smile-o" />
            <input
              // onChange={this.textChange}
              // onKeyPress={this.enterClick}
              onKeyPress={this.addCommEnter}
              onChange={this.getValue}
              className="user-input"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Add Comment..."
            />
            <button onClick={this.addComment} className="post">
              Post
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Feed;
```

It would really appreciate your comment!

Answer (score 1):

I only glanced at this question so I don't know if this is the only problem, but:

```
<ul className="feed-comments">
    <Comment commentAddList={this.states.commentList} />
</ul>
```

needs to be:

```
<ul className="feed-comments">
    <Comment commentAddList={this.state.commentList} />
</ul>
```

Comment: omg... Thank you so much.. I am struggling with this problem for several hours...

Comment: there are other places where you specified `this.states` instead of `this.state`

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean.. If you don't mind, could you explain it in detail?

Comment: Every place where you typed `this.states.commentList` you need to change to`this.state.commentList`. `this.states` isn't reference to anything in your code. `this.state` refers to the state object of the current component, which you intended to use.

Comment: ahhhh yeap yeap your right! I got the point!